# I am not getting expected result with my python code. Pl check

Tags: regex, python-3.x

> - Expected Result = (444)333-4444', '444-555-3424'
> - Actual Result = [('(444)333-4444', '(444)', '', '333', '-', '4444', '', '', ''), ('444-555-3424', '444', '-', '555', '-', '3424', '', '', '')]

```
tell_op = re.compile(r'''(
(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                # area code
(\s|-|\.)?                        # separator
(\d{3})                           # first 3 digits
(\s|-|\.)                         # separator
(\d{4})                           # last 4 digits
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?    # extension
)''', re.VERBOSE)
oo = tell_op.findall('this is my phone number (444)333-4444, 444-555-3424')
print(oo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all the inner groups [non-capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
tell_op = re.compile(r'''(
(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                    # area code
(?:\s|-|\.)?                            # separator
(?:\d{3})                               # first 3 digits
(?:\s|-|\.)                             # separator
(?:\d{4})                               # last 4 digits
(?:\s*(?:ext|x|ext.)\s*(?:\d{2,5}))?    # extension
)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

This will give you

```
['(444)333-4444', '444-555-3424']
```

Comment: also just for the info let me know why '?' doesn't work with '\d{number}'. if I code like \d{3}?, d{3} will still get picked as required condition but it should be optional.e.g.if have two numbers '333-4444' and '4444'. \d{3}?\d{4} should give me both the numbers but only '333-4444' gets printed.

Comment: @Junaid `?` does not really mean "optional", it means "zero or one" (if not preceded by `+` or `*`). `...{3}(zero or one)` does not make any sense. If you want "optionally three digits" (ie, "zero or three digits"). `(?:\d{3}-)?\d{4}` will match both `333-4444` and `4444`. This works because it uses a non-capture group to treat the 3 digits as a single group, which may appear zero or one time

Comment: thank you friend... got it quite clearly now...actually am completely a functional guy ... trying my hands in coding for fun :).. am beginner and was stuck there for sometime..but after yourself help i could extract all the legitimate phone numbers from the file. Thank you again, appreciate it !!